# Bind Sync Unknown Command

Tags: dns, bind, dnssec

Could anybody please, enlighten me on the following messages in my logs for Bind:

```
sync 127.in-addr.arpa(unknown command): 2 Time(s)
sync domain.com(unknown command): 2 Time(s)
```

It's neither an error nor a warning. It's all up and running OK and I see no problems anywhere. How do I fix it what is it all about? I cannot seem to google anything on it. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone or something is issuing commands like:

```
rndc sync 127.in-addr.arpa
rndc sync domain.com
```

but the version of BIND you're using is too old to support that command?

When you're using dynamic DNS updates, `rndc sync` will update the actual DNS data file, so that the zone's journal file becomes unnecessary and can be deleted. On older BIND versions, I think you had to use `rndc freeze` followed by `rndc thaw` to get the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for replying, teloM. Appreciate. Is that actually the output when Bind is restarted? Is it fixable somehow? Where do I check for it in Bind 9.8?

Comment: As you might know, `rndc` is the administrative tool for BIND, that can be used to send commands to a running BIND instance. Something, perhaps a DNS zone management tool, or a cron job, seems to be running those commands. [According to BIND 9.8 Administrator Reference Manual (ARM)](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.8.0/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf) pages 10-12, the `rndc` command of BIND 9.8 does not yet support the `sync` subcommand, and neither does [version 9.8.8](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.8.8/doc/arm/man.rndc.html) which seems to be the last of the 9.8.x series.

Comment: If you don't know what is issuing those commands, you might try something like `grep -r "rndc sync" /etc /root /usr/local /opt /var/spool` to find out.